# understanding the email templates

Tags: email-templates

I'm working with the email templates from system -> transactional emails. There is a call here that i don't understand.

```
  {{customVar code=PaymentInfoBox}}
```

Can someone explain what actually happens here?
I imagine it just tells it where to look for the payment information but this doesn't look like it could be a conrtoller/method path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that

```
   {{customVar code=PaymentInfoBox}}
```

is a call to a custom variable, saved under system->custom variables. The variable is called PaymentInfoBox and this is just a way of calling it.

I thought it may have been some reference to a controller as there is additional data to do with what the payment method actually was displayed in the page around where this call is made.

Answer (score 0):

Custom variables are a way to insert static content into an email template. They can be edited from the backend and is mostly useful for inserting stuff for which a static block is overkill (there is nothing in there that Magento needs to fetch) like seasonal banners, tracking pixels and blocks of markup that is specific for email.

Note: While some variables seem to work, it is by chance that they do, the feature does not seem to be fully ironed out.